# locking a file using lockfile.locksync in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, locking

I am using lockfile.locksync to lock a file in node.js. But I'd like to know the complete mechanism of this utility. So far every website says that its a "very polite lock file utility" but none explains the internal mechanism of this utility.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can find code base here if it helps https://github.com/npm/lockfile/blob/master/lockfile.js

Comment: can't figure out the mechanism

Answer (score 0):

### NODE FS

To understand file options in Node.js, take a look here [#fs_file_system_flags](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system_flags) and Linux [open()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) syscall which covers options like

O_TRUNC - truncate existing file

O_CREAT - create if not exists

O_WRONLY - access mode, write-only

O_EXCL - ensure that this call creates the file. In pair with O_CREAT triggers EEXIST error if file exists.

**But it doesn't offer file lock alternatives similar to "[flock](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html)"**

---

### NPM LOCKFILE INVESTIGATING

I tries to use npm library called "lockfile" as there are too much copy/pasted examples with it.

Verdict. "lockfile" npm library in current implementation "v1.0.4" is incomplete/useless!

From the [source](https://github.com/npm/lockfile/blob/master/lockfile.js):

```
exports.lockSync = function (path, opts) {
  opts = opts || {}
  opts.req = opts.req || req++
  debug('lockSync', path, opts)
  if (opts.wait || opts.retryWait) {
    throw new Error('opts.wait not supported sync for obvious reasons')
  }

  try {
    var fd = fs.openSync(path, wx)
    locks[path] = fd
    try { fs.closeSync(fd) } catch (er) {}
    debug('locked sync!', path, fd)
    return
```

So that 5 lines of actual code in "try{}" block just "openSync" in "wx" mode, save *"path"* to *"locks[path]"* and "closeSync".
If file exists it fails! due to "wx"!

YOU CAN'T LOCK THE EXISTING FILE with "lockfile" library!

Finally it tries to call "unlockSync" with onExit signal with this code:

```
exports.unlockSync = function (path) {
  debug('unlockSync', path)
  // best-effort.  unlocking an already-unlocked lock is a noop
  try { fs.unlinkSync(path) } catch (er) {}
  delete locks[path]
}
```

And yes, it will DELETE your file after process exited!

**This is not the file locking mechanics!**

---

### ANY RELIABLE SOLUTION FOR NODEJS FILE LOCK?

I've found [fs-ext](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-ext) works just perfect! Open 2 tabs with `node` process and check what locking file means:

## tab1

```
const fs = require("fs");
const {flockSync} = require('fs-ext');
const fd = fs.openSync('1.txt', 'w');
flockSync(fd, 'ex');
```

## tab2

```
const fs = require("fs");
const {flockSync} = require('fs-ext');
const fd = fs.openSync('1.txt', 'r');
flockSync(fd, 'sh'); // PENDING!
```

In tab2 `flockSync(fd, 'sh');` will pending until in tab1 `flockSync(fd, 'un');` is called!

It really works!